# Change category product sort order values

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-products, sorting, sort

I want to change one time all sort order values of the products inside all categories, by using a php script.

Currently all products inside all categories do got the value `1` for the sort order.

I want to change this to `10000`, so that I can easily change the sort order of the products.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: **https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52053/set-category-product-position-of-products**

Comment: @Myron Thanks, but that is not exactly what I am looking for. I need to update all products inside that category and give that the position `10000`.

Comment: What Magento version you are using?

Comment: @Sukeshini Version 1.9.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah sorry, i might have read your question wrong.

The thing i can think of is dirty but effective.

You can run a query like this:

```
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$writeConnection->query("UPDATE `catalog_category_product` SET `position`= 10000 WHERE `category_id` = 23");
```

I have tested the query on my own magento database and it works like a charm.

do note: 23 in this case was the id of a specific category so change that to the category you would like to update with the new data.

After you have run the query run a index of `product flat data` else the new data won't show up.

As I said it is dirty doing it this way.

In any other case you could try and write your own module handeling all this for you by simply adding a category id and to what number the position of the products should change to.

Comment: Thanks, but in that case I need to edit it for all categories by hand. Is there also a way to create a php script, that update all categories?

Comment: @HenkZ You could try to run this instead: `UPDATE catalog_category_product SET position= 10000`, don't forget to run index afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested below code for few products to update the positions in there categories and it worked as expected.

Place this code in a php file inside your project folder and run it. **It is highly recommended to get a backup of table `catalog_category_product` before you run the script.**

Even though  there is an API method specifically to do this, I have used direct SQL query as it eliminates most of the Magento's overhead (e.g. event observers related) if we used API. Specially when there's a large set of data required to be updated, then direct SQL queries act faster.

> I'm not encouraging to use direct SQL queries, but since this is a
>   temporal php script which you can use and throw away it would be
>   fine.

The code :

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php'; // Put your Mage.php path here
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$table = $resource->getTableName('catalog_category_product');
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$position = 10000;

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addIsActiveFilter();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $catId = $category->getId();
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET position = '{$position}' WHERE category_id = " . $catId . " AND product_id = " . $productId;
        $writeConnection->query($query);
    }
}
```